# Existence of a vector field on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g,\nabla)$ be a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and Riemannian connection $\nabla$. Let $f$ be a positive function on $M$. Does there exist a vector field $Z$ such
$$\frac{1}{f}\nabla_X\operatorname{grad} f=\nabla_XZ$$
I am looking for a complete existence result or non-existence result.

I tried $Z=\operatorname{grad}\operatorname{log} f$ and I got
$$\nabla_XZ=\nabla_X (\operatorname{grad}  \operatorname{log} f)=\nabla_X (\frac1f\operatorname{grad}  f)=\frac1f\nabla_X (\operatorname{grad}  f)-X(f) \frac1{f^2}(\operatorname{grad}  f)$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you want this to be true for all $X$?

Comment: The substitution $\phi  = \log f$ should still help you study this: I believe your condition becomes $\nabla \phi \otimes \nabla \phi + \nabla^2 \phi = \nabla Z.$ I think antisymmetrizing this should give you a necessary condition on the curvature of $g$.

Comment: This condition is equivalent to the above one. I want a condition that guarantee the existence of $Z$.

Comment: In other words, what conditions on $f$ that admits a solution for $Z$. Or what is the explicit form of $Z$ in terms of $f$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis

Comment: Yes, I know it's equivalent, I was just saying it's probably a more tractable way to write it down.

Comment: My follow-up was mistaken, though; all you can conclude from antisymmetrizing is that $\nabla Z$ will be symmetric.

Answer (score 6):

Let me begin with a general framework. Suppose $E\to M$ is a vector bundle over a manifold $M$, equipped with a connection $\nabla$, thus, defining a differential
$$
d_\nabla: \Omega^0(M,E)\to \Omega^1(M, E). 
$$
This differential extends to higher degree forms with values in $E$:
$$
d_\nabla: \Omega^k(M,E)\to \Omega^{k+1}(M,E).
$$
The **curvature** of $\nabla$ is the composition
$$
F_\nabla= d^2_\nabla= d_\nabla\circ d_\nabla:  \Omega^0(M,E)\to \Omega^2(M, E).
$$
Unless $\nabla$ is flat, the complex above is not a chain complex, however, the 2nd Bianchi identity reads as
$$
d^3_\nabla= 0. 
$$
It is natural to ask:

> Q1. Which forms $\omega\in \Omega^1(M,E)$ are "exact," i.e. lie in the image of $d_\nabla$?

> Q2. More generally one can ask the same question for degree $k$ forms $\omega$, $k\ge 2$.

It is clear that for the equation
$$
d_\nabla \zeta= \omega
$$
(with given $\omega$ and the unknown $\zeta$) to have a solution, the form $\omega$ has to satisfy the condition
$$
d_\nabla \omega\in Im(F_\nabla),
$$
i.e. there exists a section $\eta\in \Omega^0(M,E)$ such that
$$
d_\nabla \omega= F_\nabla \eta.
$$
In other words, for every $p\in M$ and every pair of tangent vectors $X, Y\in T_pM$, there exists a vector $Z\in E_p$ such that
$$
(d_\nabla \omega)(X,Y)= F_\nabla(X,Y,Z)\in E_p. 
$$

In terms of $\omega$ itself, a necessary (but insufficient) condition is
$$
d^2_\nabla \omega=0. 
$$

A reasonable conjecture is:

> If $M$ is contractible, then the necessary condition $d_\nabla \omega\in Im(F_\nabla)$ is also sufficient for the existence of $\eta$ such that $\omega=d_\nabla \eta$.

In this case when $\nabla$ is flat, this is indeed the case and is a special case of the Poincar'e Lemma.  While there is some literature on this subject for general (non-flat) connections, I do not really understand if it provides an answer (but I did not sped much time exploring the literature). The impression I have from reading is that the answer is along the lines of "locally, curvature determines the  connection, up to gauge transformation." However, I do not see how to apply it to the above question in the setting of general vector bundles, or specifically, to affine connections on the tangent bundle.

I will, therefore, consider the case of flat connections and simply-connected manifolds $M$. Then $(E,\nabla)$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle with trivial connection on $M$ and, thus, the equation $d_\nabla \zeta= \omega$ (with given $\omega\in \Omega^1(M,E)$) has a solution if and only if $d_\nabla \omega=0$.

Next, let's specialize to the case of affine connections on the tangent bundle $E=(TM\to M)$. The problem you are posing can be reformulated as:

> What are the conditions on a smooth positive function $f$ on $M$, for the existence of a vector-field $Z\in {\mathfrak X}(M)$ such that
> $$
> \frac{1}{f} d_\nabla grad(f)= d_\nabla Z,
> $$
> where $d_\nabla: \Omega^0(M,TM)= {\mathfrak X}(M)\to \Omega^1(M, TM)$ is the covariant differential associated with $\nabla$.

What's written above provides a partial answer. I use the notation
$$
H_f= d_\nabla grad(f).
$$

1. The necessary condition for solvability of the equation
   $$
   \frac{1}{f} H_f= d_\nabla Z
   $$
   is that
   $$
   d_\nabla( \frac{1}{f} H_f)\in Image(F_\nabla). 
   $$
   Conjecturally, this condition is also sufficient if $M$ is contractible.
2. If $\nabla$ is flat and $M$ is simply-connected, then the above necessary condition, which simply reads
   $$
   d_\nabla( \frac{1}{f} H_f)=0,
   $$
   is also sufficient for solving the equation
   $$
   \frac{1}{f} H_f= d_\nabla Z.
   $$

I will now spell out what this means in local coordinates, assuming flatness of $\nabla$.

Thus, I assume that $M$ is a simply-connected domain in ${\mathbb R}^n$ equipped with the standard flat metric and the trivial connection $\nabla$ and $E\to M$ is just the tangent bundle. Then a 1-form $\omega\in \Omega^1(M, E)$ is an $n$-tuple of ordinary 1-forms
$$
\omega_1,...,\omega_n\in \Omega^1(M), \omega_i= \sum_{j=1}^n a^i_j dx^j
$$
defining a matrix-valued function $x\mapsto A(x)$, $A=(a^i_j)$. The problem about vector-valued forms  then becomes:

> For which matrix-valued functions $A$ there exists a vector-field $Z$ such that $DZ=A$, where $D$ is the Jacobian derivative?

> Equivalently: which $n$-tuples of $1$-forms $(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)$ are (simultaneously) exact?

The answer, as noted above is: If and only if $d\omega_i=0$ for all $i=1,...,n$, equivalently,
$$
(*) ~~~~~~~\frac{\partial a^i_j}{\partial x_k}= \frac{\partial a^i_k}{\partial x_j}, 1\le i, j, k\le n. 
$$

You are interested in the special case when $A$ has the form
$$
A= \frac{1}{f} H_f
$$
where $H_f$ is the Hessian of a smooth positive function $f$ on $M$ (which, I recall, is an open simply-connected subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$). The closedness condition for $\omega$ above in terms of partial derivatives then becomes (this is an elementary calculus computation which I skip)
$$
f_k f_{ij}= f_j f_{ik}
$$
provided that $f\in C^3(M)$, where the subscripts refer to partial derivatives. This is a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a vector field $Z$ in your question (again assuming flatness of the Riemannian metric and simply-connected domain).

---

Edit. Since you really want to see a calculation, here it is, as I said, all you need to know is how to use the Ratio Rule:

The matrix $A= \frac{1}{f}H_f$ (where $H_f$ is the usual Hessian) has the entries:
$$
a_{ij}= \frac{1}{f} f_{ij},
$$
where $f_{ij}= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}f$. The equation (*) becomes:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(\frac{f_{ij}}{f})= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\frac{f_{ik}}{f}). 
$$
Applying the Ratio Rule to both sides of the equation, we obtain:
$$
\frac{-f_k f_{ij} + f f_{ijk}}{f^2}= \frac{-f_j f_{ik} + f f_{ikj}}{f^2}.
$$
Since $f\in C^3$, $f_{ijk}= f_{ikj}$. Hence, cancelling equal terms on both sides, we get:
$$
\frac{f_k f_{ij}}{f^2}= \frac{f_j f_{ik}}{f^2}.
$$
Cancelling the denominators on both sides, we then get:
$$
f_k f_{ij}= f_j f_{ik},
$$
just as I promised.

Lastly: My favorite source for covariant differentials on vector bundles and their relation to Riemannian Geometry is

Jürgen Jost, Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis, Berlin: Springer-Verlag. xi, 401 p. (1995). [ZBL0828.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0828.53002).

The nice thing about Jost's book is that he does not skip routine computations and is not afraid to state and repeat obvious things, which is quite useful for a beginner.

Comment: Dear @moishe Thank you for your answer. How did you get this condition? Does this condition guarantee the existence of a function whose gradient is $Z$. One more thing, I guess Poincare Lemma is true in simply connected manifolds, not only flat one, is not it?

Comment: @Semsem: I will add more details a bit later, when I have more time. My answer is for the problem where $f$ is given and $Z$ is unknown, not the other way around. For non-flat manifolds I would have to deal with the equation $d_\nabla \eta= \omega$ for the given bundle-valued form $\omega$ and the trouble comes from the fact that $d_\nabla^2\ne 0$ (= curvature of the connection). There is some literature on "nonabelian Poincare lemma" dealing with the more general exactness equation $d_\nabla \eta= \omega$ but I must confess, I do not entirely understand what is going on there.

Comment: @Semsem: See the edit.

Comment: I will wear the down-vote on this answer as a badge of honor.

Comment: Please,  do not misunderstand me. I am really unpleased with your answer. Most of the notations in your edits does not meet my knowledge. I was looking for a simple answer as my question id.

Comment: The only request i asked you for, you did not provide in your edits and skipped it

Comment: Finally i am sorry for that. I take my downvote back and +1. I am still need an answer.